# Cassandra node not starting; commit log file issue?

Tags: cassandra

I am having issues starting a Cassandra node.  Here is the error:

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file C:\apache-cassandra-3_extracted\apache-cassandra-3.10\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1497856002934.log
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:153) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readAllFiles(CommitLogReader.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replayFiles(CommitLogReplayer.java:140) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverFiles(CommitLog.java:177) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverSegmentsOnDisk(CommitLog.java:158) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:326) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
            at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
```

Does anyone know how I can get it started?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem reading the commitlog while starting. You should check if the file is perhaps empty or has wrong permissions.

If there are more than this single node on your cluster - and you have a replication factor higher than one, simply delete this single commitlog file and try starting up cassandra again and run a repair.

This should also work on single node or replication factor one - but with data loss for the upserts in this logfile.